# How to start up of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

After finishing environment variable and my.ini, i still can't start MySQL on Windows through DBeaver. It just return "System error 5: rejection  to visit". While i starting cmd as an Administrator, it returns "System error 2 : file can't be find".I hope i can start MySQL. After finishing environment variable and my.ini, i still can't start MySQL on Windows through DBeaver. It just return "System error 5: rejection  to visit". While i starting cmd as an Administrator, it returns "System error 2 : file can't be find".I hope i can start MySQL.

Comment: 1) Provide complete and precise, not approximate, error message text. 2) Provide precise command line which causes the error. 3) MySQL should be started as a service.